# How do I fix my MBR when windows 7 system recovery shows no drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, mbr

I accidentally pulled the power plug when my system was starting up, and I started to get a boot error after POST. Something like "something not found, insert a bootable disk and press enter"

So I put in my windows 7 x64 CD - and clicked through repair computer. At the system recovery options screen, there are no drives listed. (There is only one drive in the computer)

Even if I click through the use recovery tools option (without selecting a drive), and enter command prompt - typing C: gives me this error:

```
X:\Sources>c:
The system cannot find the drive specified.
X:\Sources>
```

So I pulled the drive out, and attached it to a different computer. I went into disk management - and oddly the drive shows 128GB (it's a 64gb drive) and the area next to it is black. I clicked simple partition (which works), but when I try to format - it gives me an error that it's unable to format the drive.

I would prefer to not format the drive if possible...there is one file that is important (I know i can recover it with some program, I just don't want to if avoidable)

How do I fix this?

EDIT:

I can now access C: in the windows 7 DVD recovery tools command prompt - what do i do now?

Comment: Sounds like your drive is cooked.

Comment: it's a SSD - I doubt it... it seems to me like a software problem. Drive was not dropped, there was nothing to cause overvoltage, nothing spilled, no static, etc.

Comment: That he can't format it also leads me to think the problem is greater than software.

Comment: @AmpedWeb: What happens if you do `DiskPart` and then `List Disk`? If the disk appears, can you do `Select Disk 0` (or whatever the number is), followed by `List Partition`? What does it say?

Comment: @Mehrdad: When I do List Disk - it shows Disk 1 online size: 128GB free: 128gb. I then do Select Disk 1 and List Partition - and it says there are no partitions on this disk to show

Comment: @AmpedWeb: And you said it's a 64-GB drive? That doesn't look good... I suggest you try to use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) (be **extremely** careful!!) and see if there's anything in the partition table that might be hinting at why. Chances are you won't find anything, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @AmpedWeb: Oh by the way, how did you access C: in the DVD recovery tools when there were no partitions? Did you make a new one?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, in my other computer I made a simple partition using disk management in the hopes that I could do a quick format - and then recover files using a file recovery program. But the format didn't take - and the recovery program isn't seeing the files on the drive

Comment: @Mehrdad any idea how I should use TestDisk to try to recover my disk?

Comment: @AmpedWeb: I don't think it's a great idea to do something like that -- you don't want to modify anything on the disk when you're trying to recover it. If you have an external drive, I suggest you try this: Get a Linux boot disk (Ubuntu should be fine), and *carefully* use the `dd` command to copy *the entire disk* onto another file, as backup. That way if you mess something up, the contents are still there.

Comment: As for TestDisk: I'm not sure -- it depends on a lot of things. Now that you've created a new partition and destroyed the old ones that might have been there, though, the partition table won't have much info. Just back up everything with `dd` first (make sure you can't accidentally delete the backup!!), and *then* start playing around with TestDisk, so that you don't mess anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether or not you can even see the drive in BIOS. If you can't then it isn't the drive's problem. . .

**edit**

Now that you are able to see the drive, you need to fix the MBR.  I would follow these steps:

I recommend the `bootrec` command.

First try `bootrec /fixmbr`
then try  `bootrec /fixboot`

Then, if that doesn't work, try rebuilding the BCD. Microsoft's original instructions has you exporting the old BCD.  To heck with that.

> cd c:\boot 
>   attrib bcd -s -h -r 
>   ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old 
>   bootrec /RebuildBcd

Comment: I can see the drive in bios, I have also edited the original problem - please see changes

Comment: Try **repair my system**.  If that doesn't work, try the commands at the recovery console.